# How to download a video when I get the URL of the MP4 file in selenium python? (WITHOUT URLLIB)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I can get to the point where the video is right in front of me. I need to loop through the urls and download all of these videos. The issue is that the request is stateful and I cannot use urllib because then authorization issues occur. How do I just target the three dots in chrome video viewer and download the file?

All I need now is to be able to download by clicking on the download button. I do not know if it can be done without the specification of coordinates. Like I said, the urls follow a pattern and I can generate them. The only issue is the authorization. Please help me get the videos through selenium.

Note that the video is in JavaScript so I cannot really target the three dots or the download button.

Comment: Please post the site link. And also post what kind of authorization you have to handle. It is difficult to guide without clear understanding of what is available, what you have tried and what are our options.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the cookies from the driver and pass the information to the Request session. So, you can download with the **Requests** library.

```
import requests

cookies = driver.get_cookies()
s = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])
response = s.get(urlDownload, stream=True)
print(response.status_code)
with open(fileName,'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use selenium in python 2 as you have only pics i cannot give you a real code but something like that will help.you can find XPath by inspecting HTML

```
    import selenium 
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath of 3 dots')
```